# Не могу использовать машину, к которой подключен через VPN , как DNS сервер

Tags: dns, vpn, openvpn

Есть 2 машины.

1-ая — сервер опенвпн и днс сервер, вторая - клиент. Не могу, будучи клиентом использовать 10.8.0.1 как DNS, потому что не работает.

1-ая

- Внешний ip - 1.1.1.1
- Локальный ip - 192.168.199.2
- OpenVPN ip - 10.8.0.1

2-ая

- Внешний ip - 2.2.2.2
- Локальный ip - 192.168.1.2
- OpenVPN ip - 10.8.0.2

Машины пингуются

Конфиг сервера опенвпн

```
dev tun
proto tcp
port 12345
ca ca.crt
cert server.crt
key server.key 
dh dh1024.pem
topology subnet
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
cipher AES-128-CBC
comp-lzo
mssfix
keepalive 10 120
verb 3
```

Конфиг клиента

```
client
dev tun
proto tcp
remote 1.1.1.1 12345
ca ca.crt
cert sixth.crt
key sixth.key
cipher AES-128-CBC
nobind
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
```

Подскажите , что я не учёл.
Заранее спасибо.

---

nslookup domen.com - показывает ip 10.8.0.1